# How do I plot a rate?

Tags: statistics

How do I plot a rate? I've got a rate of exponential growth per year and I want to plot this, and see where it gets to in 10 years, or a thousand years.

Comment: Plot the derivative!

Answer (score 1):

You could plot the function $e^{rt}$ for different values of $t$ with $r$ being your annual exponential growth rate. Then you could evaluate this function at $t=10$ or $t=1000$. 
 Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Plot in with a log scale on the y axis. Then the line will be straight and it will be easy to see where it is going.